# 17.04 ubuntu launcher not showing

Tags: launcher, display, 17.04

That launcher has suddenly disappeared and I'm unable to open any apps I.e Libre, trash etc. It was operating but has suddenly stopped appearing on the screen. The files are still on the system. How can I reinitialize it without loosing my files on the system. Please keep the explanations simple as I'm not computer literate

Comment: Check if it shows up pressing the SUPER key (usually the one with the windows logo) or if you can reach the "insert command" bar pressing ALT.

Comment: Hi velix have tried the super key but nothing happens as well as with the ALT